# Bitcoin Core Error

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

I'm having an issue downloading the bitcoin blockchain on a new computer. I downloaded it all day yesterday without issue (80% downloaded) and then when I woke up this morning the computer was still on but Bitcoin Core was closed. I looked at the error log and didn't see any reason as to why it closed.

**Here's the debug log from first thing in the morning prior; no errors or anything that stands out to me, it just abruptly ends:**

```
2021-09-08T23:31:58Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000005563501223bafb3891246b77e5c4073aeae530c6248e8 height=640473 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140485 tx=551410308 date='2020-07-23T21:14:04Z' progress=0.814075 cache=620.1MiB(4598814txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:58Z Pre-allocating up to position 0xa00000 in rev02164.dat
2021-09-08T23:31:58Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000001c52b3957bdf667d91e4c5d9b6a9a356391584cfc93ba height=640474 version=0x213ce000 log2_work=92.140504 tx=551412682 date='2020-07-23T21:15:56Z' progress=0.814079 cache=620.3MiB(4600748txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:58Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000028d93728cf20173e2429fd420b1403f23ad796bc329b7 height=640475 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=92.140524 tx=551415405 date='2020-07-23T21:45:22Z' progress=0.814083 cache=621.1MiB(4606984txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:58Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000782c530e95dfe40d9d5123de95f076c8dff407ff4709c height=640476 version=0x20800000 log2_work=92.140544 tx=551418323 date='2020-07-23T21:49:53Z' progress=0.814087 cache=621.5MiB(4609969txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:58Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x6000000 in blk02164.dat
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000bd65f7d9aa52d6edb94f64cd89ca61d55f78184bc2f48 height=640477 version=0x20400000 log2_work=92.140563 tx=551420321 date='2020-07-23T22:01:37Z' progress=0.814090 cache=621.7MiB(4611598txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000020f34853fe2fbe60fc85fb565fdf836dcd1cebf85bab4 height=640478 version=0x2000e000 log2_work=92.140583 tx=551423061 date='2020-07-23T22:04:49Z' progress=0.814094 cache=621.8MiB(4612702txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000002a351a5ce1da09275292a4f29fe0da1f5d71d5d4a1152 height=640479 version=0x3fffe000 log2_work=92.140603 tx=551425784 date='2020-07-23T22:20:00Z' progress=0.814098 cache=622.3MiB(4617015txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z Pre-allocating up to position 0xb00000 in rev02164.dat
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000fb73db28e5f1301cebbad2e52c77603df1a17752ec9d1 height=640480 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140622 tx=551428139 date='2020-07-23T22:23:37Z' progress=0.814101 cache=622.5MiB(4618280txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000bd653beb42298ed429349409f4691dcc0a128d266b5c8 height=640481 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140642 tx=551430902 date='2020-07-23T22:27:22Z' progress=0.814106 cache=622.6MiB(4619511txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000085b8d4c2421620105bf791537f189865fec4f1ce5da00 height=640482 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140662 tx=551433724 date='2020-07-23T22:41:10Z' progress=0.814110 cache=623.0MiB(4622369txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000207ae83189d266efe542ff1c75a5a786c48e51c47ebef height=640483 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140681 tx=551436723 date='2020-07-23T23:29:16Z' progress=0.814114 cache=623.6MiB(4627290txo)
2021-09-08T23:31:59Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000006e4e27f0948f0bbb287ca2aa3e656957cbafc13b85dd9 height=640484 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140701 tx=551438919 date='2020-07-23T23:34:05Z' progress=0.814117 cache=624.2MiB(4632088txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:00Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000c303b32ea99d210ff0ea302190b9357cf89a98b551710 height=640485 version=0x20002000 log2_work=92.140721 tx=551441463 date='2020-07-23T23:42:47Z' progress=0.814121 cache=624.4MiB(4634159txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:00Z Pre-allocating up to position 0xc00000 in rev02164.dat
2021-09-08T23:32:00Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000034e6ec6f7103cb66cdb88dcbf41e812d0bf99ad7f7225 height=640486 version=0x20a00000 log2_work=92.140741 tx=551444478 date='2020-07-23T23:47:56Z' progress=0.814126 cache=624.6MiB(4635765txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:00Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x7000000 in blk02164.dat
2021-09-08T23:32:00Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000030e754949b07f8938c6e33af3a8997999f138fa0ea42a height=640487 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140760 tx=551446952 date='2020-07-23T23:49:38Z' progress=0.814129 cache=624.7MiB(4636221txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:00Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000c8df12658e8ec998620604c9b87b2ab9bbd05a6392442 height=640488 version=0x37ffe000 log2_work=92.140780 tx=551449688 date='2020-07-23T23:58:19Z' progress=0.814133 cache=624.9MiB(4638230txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000002bae89497d9d54ad3935c1ce967ec6841614aa6f9cc8e height=640489 version=0x3fff0000 log2_work=92.140800 tx=551451827 date='2020-07-24T00:18:48Z' progress=0.814136 cache=625.2MiB(4640337txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000053e1d81dac567b62fa7e398014e2f0cafaa56693d81f9 height=640490 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140819 tx=551454132 date='2020-07-24T00:33:38Z' progress=0.814140 cache=625.4MiB(4642170txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000934c59b7cbb1fdc017dccea74a9053cf6010845d9f1f2 height=640491 version=0x2fffe000 log2_work=92.140839 tx=551456665 date='2020-07-24T00:36:43Z' progress=0.814144 cache=625.7MiB(4644437txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000f9b6cd79444b4a5a21b7ffeebc722e5c4fa5e2dcec054 height=640492 version=0x3fffc000 log2_work=92.140859 tx=551459125 date='2020-07-24T00:39:44Z' progress=0.814147 cache=625.7MiB(4644721txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z Pre-allocating up to position 0xd00000 in rev02164.dat
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000102ce96ba14985415161bf8ee47a4f2e1bcbf1de4f1290 height=640493 version=0x3fff0000 log2_work=92.140878 tx=551462183 date='2020-07-24T00:43:56Z' progress=0.814152 cache=626.0MiB(4647293txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000067a5294c0f226fab3b7414129fac9f510e546e2cb84f6 height=640494 version=0x3fff0000 log2_work=92.140898 tx=551464110 date='2020-07-24T00:47:10Z' progress=0.814155 cache=625.8MiB(4645799txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000007bb38f4292e92598c9020785ea6c0436d42badf620755 height=640495 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140918 tx=551466399 date='2020-07-24T00:51:23Z' progress=0.814158 cache=625.8MiB(4645838txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000f11a801df26b3255bc45fb2981d48b41e62104a0ad876 height=640496 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.140937 tx=551469018 date='2020-07-24T01:10:15Z' progress=0.814162 cache=626.3MiB(4649265txo)
2021-09-08T23:32:01Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x8000000 in blk02164.dat
```

I opened Bitcoin QT and just tried to have it keep grabbing blocks to see if it would finish downloading or if it would run into an error. I left and once again came back to a computer that was still on, but Bitcoin Core was closed.

**Here's the debug log from this second closure; similarly no clear errors and just an abrupt ending**

```
2021-09-09T13:51:10Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x2000000 in blk02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:10Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x200000 in rev02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:10Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000490377763cb445efc3e9f32920015b9a3db83f987203d height=663439 version=0x37ffe000 log2_work=92.549168 tx=600597532 date='2020-12-29T03:09:31Z' progress=0.886178 cache=508.2MiB(3678800txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:10Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000002d822871dcdb027c76ee664fbd34b0a4ce0fe5790b314 height=663440 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=92.549183 tx=600599068 date='2020-12-29T03:18:43Z' progress=0.886181 cache=508.5MiB(3680961txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:11Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000088638da4d75e14561054ab853656030b108c342d5c579 height=663441 version=0x20200000 log2_work=92.549199 tx=600601594 date='2020-12-29T03:21:14Z' progress=0.886182 cache=508.7MiB(3683016txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:11Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000007fe954c14c85c642f166854d290edc9c2eff544b11cbf height=663442 version=0x20800000 log2_work=92.549215 tx=600603460 date='2020-12-29T03:24:31Z' progress=0.886183 cache=508.6MiB(3682442txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:11Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000000db7853b8fb67ad01058a075192129a37b807ef468d4d height=663443 version=0x2fffe000 log2_work=92.549231 tx=600606423 date='2020-12-29T04:32:02Z' progress=0.886202 cache=509.6MiB(3689993txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:11Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000015e313fc4efc42c8b7409f7a302a79dcc13b19285b214 height=663444 version=0x20200000 log2_work=92.549247 tx=600608928 date='2020-12-29T04:44:08Z' progress=0.886206 cache=510.6MiB(3698410txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:12Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x300000 in rev02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:12Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000f0c1b156f4fa0ca7097e05d7edb6fe736d1785e36752b height=663445 version=0x3fffc000 log2_work=92.549263 tx=600611169 date='2020-12-29T05:00:14Z' progress=0.886211 cache=511.0MiB(3701621txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:12Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000a8497eb385c4e32d5791a3f270c4cec0a4be00c154ad5 height=663446 version=0x20400000 log2_work=92.549279 tx=600613186 date='2020-12-29T05:06:59Z' progress=0.886213 cache=511.8MiB(3708619txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:12Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000011e1496a60009ebe7d5be88425e81d33c9b2392c0e7e height=663447 version=0x2000e000 log2_work=92.549295 tx=600614422 date='2020-12-29T05:10:30Z' progress=0.886214 cache=512.6MiB(3714608txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:12Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000092568ba329eefbdfd1aa2d4eaf6262f36e7e93d9f66ae height=663448 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=92.549311 tx=600616551 date='2020-12-29T05:10:37Z' progress=0.886214 cache=512.6MiB(3715029txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:13Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000bbbdc2dad8381470bafb83f9f43524ef80e53a5b23219 height=663449 version=0x20800000 log2_work=92.549327 tx=600617766 date='2020-12-29T05:18:54Z' progress=0.886217 cache=512.3MiB(3712245txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:13Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x400000 in rev02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:13Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000a614d2ac4115aef7274f922fac80383bfc3f29d74354a height=663450 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.549343 tx=600620257 date='2020-12-29T05:47:00Z' progress=0.886225 cache=512.8MiB(3716801txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:13Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000290c126b351416c79592e1a8b4d432239a9f6a03f7580 height=663451 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.549358 tx=600622019 date='2020-12-29T05:58:14Z' progress=0.886228 cache=513.6MiB(3722584txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:14Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000154b1ce36b779533a157e8acbee9d17bbb210eb6823bd height=663452 version=0x3fffe000 log2_work=92.549374 tx=600624206 date='2020-12-29T06:00:00Z' progress=0.886229 cache=513.8MiB(3724299txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:14Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x3000000 in blk02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:14Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000009dd0fd81ee5b4c37ea0e7855bde1fcf0ee9e59d877f63 height=663453 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.549390 tx=600625186 date='2020-12-29T06:05:33Z' progress=0.886231 cache=513.6MiB(3723313txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:14Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000022e7b27a1da44b018c54853898ec78a05a22dfa082d3c height=663454 version=0x20400000 log2_work=92.549406 tx=600626657 date='2020-12-29T06:12:23Z' progress=0.886233 cache=513.4MiB(3721667txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:14Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000001d19f88e3bb2af7ee165ae731f14fc1ff0f5558aa6cb7 height=663455 version=0x27ffe000 log2_work=92.549422 tx=600628860 date='2020-12-29T06:34:15Z' progress=0.886240 cache=514.1MiB(3727192txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:15Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x500000 in rev02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:15Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000005fd615b3722e74b0b3ebccab1b61e4fc2d4e07a3be70b height=663456 version=0x20866000 log2_work=92.549438 tx=600631239 date='2020-12-29T07:07:07Z' progress=0.886249 cache=514.7MiB(3731902txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:15Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000005194b1728dd30f2d4400369d912dcbc0a9f8aa29715d9 height=663457 version=0x20200000 log2_work=92.549454 tx=600632967 date='2020-12-29T07:14:41Z' progress=0.886251 cache=515.4MiB(3738019txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:15Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000948db83841b18fdeeee1aa1f8bf8881b2c351b336c27f height=663458 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.549470 tx=600634195 date='2020-12-29T07:16:13Z' progress=0.886252 cache=516.0MiB(3742654txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:16Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000aaf53dcf4ea1180c46b6e02a3025ef5c628437865d710 height=663459 version=0x2fffe000 log2_work=92.549486 tx=600636299 date='2020-12-29T07:31:12Z' progress=0.886256 cache=516.6MiB(3747875txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:16Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000093e58579bdad88dd5aaeb8108fc3964b369e9a3a5a0b2 height=663460 version=0x200ae000 log2_work=92.549502 tx=600638529 date='2020-12-29T07:39:17Z' progress=0.886259 cache=517.0MiB(3750977txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:16Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x600000 in rev02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:16Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000003b5f2dcde29d8ff54d09807ee77437b1c067edacf42d6 height=663461 version=0x2fffe000 log2_work=92.549517 tx=600640357 date='2020-12-29T07:45:54Z' progress=0.886261 cache=517.0MiB(3751126txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:17Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000e24af82ecb89ec003b0d543d5dcd6a0c8a29586648220 height=663462 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.549533 tx=600641670 date='2020-12-29T07:53:38Z' progress=0.886264 cache=516.9MiB(3750281txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:17Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x4000000 in blk02382.dat
2021-09-09T13:51:17Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000ce9330ae069bf0e84126b156025a348cb50855c41f1a1 height=663463 version=0x20400000 log2_work=92.549549 tx=600643239 date='2020-12-29T08:06:53Z' progress=0.886267 cache=517.0MiB(3751231txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:17Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000023eaf4eb39f96390b6dbe27325727dcdd069061a0b824 height=663464 version=0x2000e000 log2_work=92.549565 tx=600646290 date='2020-12-29T08:48:41Z' progress=0.886279 cache=517.9MiB(3758196txo)
2021-09-09T13:51:18Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000000aa9396430c7e531e2add394184108cfc79d978b66c42 height=663465 version=0x23c74000 log2_work=92.549581 tx=600648572 date='2020-12-29T08:55:56Z' progress=0.886282 cache=518.5MiB(3763433txo)
```

I tried again to just run Bitcoin QT to see if it could finish grabbing the blocks or if an error would at least populate. It did shortly after populate some errors saying something among the lines of "couldn't access block #### data" (in hindsight I should've screenshotted the error popup).

**Here's the debug log from this third closure when an error populated. This one similarly ended abruptly at the bottom of the debug file, but it at least had some errors earlier in the debug file (the only time that the word error was referenced in any of these files). After the Error, it seems to resume as normal, and then just cut off abruptly**

```
2021-09-09T17:57:58Z Bitcoin Core version v0.21.1 (release build)
2021-09-09T17:57:58Z Qt 5.9.8 (static), plugin=windows (static)
2021-09-09T17:57:58Z System: Windows 10 (10.0), x86_64-little_endian-llp64
2021-09-09T17:57:58Z Screen: \\.\DISPLAY1 1920x1080, pixel ratio=1.0
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000000b9d2ec5a352ecba0592946514a92f14319dc2b367fc72 have valid signatures.
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=00000000000000000000000000000000000000001533efd8d716a517fe2c5008
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using the 'sse4(1way),sse41(4way),avx2(8way)' SHA256 implementation
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using RdSeed as additional entropy source
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using RdRand as an additional entropy source
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z GUI: "registerShutdownBlockReason: Successfully registered: Bitcoin Core didn't yet exit safely..."
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Default data directory C:\Users\mkunke\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using data directory D:\Bitcoin
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Config file: D:\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf (not found, skipping)
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using at most 125 automatic connections (2048 file descriptors available)
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Script verification uses 15 additional threads
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z scheduler thread start
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using wallet directory D:\Bitcoin
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z init message: Loading banlist...
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z SetNetworkActive: true
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using /16 prefix for IP bucketing
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Cache configuration:
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z * Using 2.0 MiB for block index database
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z * Using 8.0 MiB for chain state database
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z * Using 440.0 MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1 MiB of unused mempool space)
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z init message: Loading block index...
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Switching active chainstate to Chainstate [ibd] @ height -1 (null)
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Opening LevelDB in D:\Bitcoin\blocks\index
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2021-09-09T17:57:59Z Using obfuscation key for D:\Bitcoin\blocks\index: 0000000000000000
2021-09-09T17:58:03Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 2374
2021-09-09T17:58:03Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=77, size=98034205, heights=662605...662699, time=2020-12-23...2020-12-23)
2021-09-09T17:58:03Z Checking all blk files are present...
2021-09-09T17:58:07Z Opening LevelDB in D:\Bitcoin\chainstate
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z Using obfuscation key for D:\Bitcoin\chainstate: add8b62e7469c95f
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z Loaded best chain: hashBestChain=0000000000000000000e258ec51aec8c861c0d9bb63d4ae7ae53aa4c73bb1020 height=662688 date=2020-12-23T21:00:05Z progress=0.883766
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z init message: Rewinding blocks...
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z FlushStateToDisk: write coins cache to disk (0 coins, 0kB) started
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z FlushStateToDisk: write coins cache to disk (0 coins, 0kB) completed (0.00s)
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z init message: Verifying blocks...
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z Verifying last 6 blocks at level 3
2021-09-09T17:58:08Z [0%]...[16%]...[33%]...[50%]...[66%]...[83%]...[99%]...[DONE].
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z No coin database inconsistencies in last 6 blocks (15829 transactions)
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z  block index           28085ms
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z block tree size = 699774
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z nBestHeight = 662688
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z loadblk thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z Failed to open mempool file from disk. Continuing anyway.
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z loadblk thread exit
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z torcontrol thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z Bound to [::]:8333
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z Bound to 0.0.0.0:8333
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z Bound to 127.0.0.1:8334
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z init message: Loading P2P addresses...
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z Loaded 20008 addresses from peers.dat  51ms
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z ERROR: DeserializeFileDB: Failed to open file D:\Bitcoin\anchors.dat
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z 0 block-relay-only anchors will be tried for connections.
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z init message: Starting network threads...
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z net thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z init message: Done loading
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z msghand thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z opencon thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z addcon thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z dnsseed thread start
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z Waiting 300 seconds before querying DNS seeds.
2021-09-09T17:58:27Z GUI: Platform customization: "windows"
2021-09-09T17:58:39Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=0 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:58:39Z Synchronizing blockheaders, height: 699792 (~100.00%)
2021-09-09T17:58:56Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=699792, peer=1 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:00Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000c1ba8d27fcfaf18003c6c421be786102845280c44b8bc height=662689 version=0x3fff0000 log2_work=92.537153 tx=599049054 date='2020-12-23T21:01:17Z' progress=0.883767 cache=1.3MiB(9697txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:02Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000048a890969858feffb5799cd8b3d181abd1a4fc650828e height=662690 version=0x20800000 log2_work=92.537169 tx=599052096 date='2020-12-23T21:31:23Z' progress=0.883775 cache=3.1MiB(23847txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:03Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=3 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:04Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=4 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:07Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000eee8c803be0399a70e8f6b025efc452fd08c6c8fe4281 height=662691 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.537186 tx=599054418 date='2020-12-23T21:37:21Z' progress=0.883777 cache=5.3MiB(39829txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:07Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x7000000 in blk02374.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:08Z Pre-allocating up to position 0xe00000 in rev02374.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:08Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000037cb93e33afa7b8602200b52da5a25301948113f08eb2 height=662692 version=0x3fffe000 log2_work=92.537202 tx=599056707 date='2020-12-23T21:52:04Z' progress=0.883782 cache=6.9MiB(52671txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:10Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000b3e12b5a3f987108530552865187ca9e54ff4db9d14c9 height=662693 version=0x20800000 log2_work=92.537218 tx=599059109 date='2020-12-23T21:57:23Z' progress=0.883784 cache=8.8MiB(64894txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:11Z P2P peers available. Skipped DNS seeding.
2021-09-09T17:59:11Z dnsseed thread exit
2021-09-09T17:59:11Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000008a73096daf3c93d4bd2a522b8ae0ebef1f6c7e6ab264b height=662694 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.537234 tx=599061269 date='2020-12-23T22:13:38Z' progress=0.883788 cache=10.0MiB(74645txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:13Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000018d97426bb381ac72d02016e657b7bd7bd9e881a5c851 height=662695 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.537250 tx=599062040 date='2020-12-23T22:17:28Z' progress=0.883790 cache=10.7MiB(80878txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:14Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000006ed4f893349a9f5691997b330cc50a743f0e0dcf20878 height=662696 version=0x2000e000 log2_work=92.537266 tx=599064116 date='2020-12-23T22:26:45Z' progress=0.883793 cache=11.9MiB(90673txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:16Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000082481a27331e7ca59d026a64115ac5e5dd5a88c8deac1 height=662697 version=0x37ffe000 log2_work=92.537282 tx=599066758 date='2020-12-23T22:42:17Z' progress=0.883797 cache=13.3MiB(101699txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:16Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x8000000 in blk02374.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:17Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000eb39f672b7b8c95f746d20a1e6e82020bf72ededf3e55 height=662698 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.537298 tx=599069197 date='2020-12-23T22:44:37Z' progress=0.883798 cache=15.4MiB(111981txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:19Z Pre-allocating up to position 0xf00000 in rev02374.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:19Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000de3d0fa490ba71d70dc93a3d50123a9dfcd321e922167 height=662699 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=92.537314 tx=599071547 date='2020-12-23T22:45:33Z' progress=0.883799 cache=16.4MiB(119961txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:21Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000008e4fb355290a4a792e07f3bb0739dd1775eaba561bd68 height=662700 version=0x20000000 log2_work=92.537330 tx=599073992 date='2020-12-23T22:47:15Z' progress=0.883800 cache=17.5MiB(128968txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:21Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=699792, peer=5 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:22Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000004751166eb0b2f9b9d31605a0ae286e8cec32dc5a4c769 height=662701 version=0x2fffe000 log2_work=92.537346 tx=599076737 date='2020-12-23T22:50:11Z' progress=0.883801 cache=18.7MiB(139256txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:23Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000059b480eea832cd43e43405077fa5ea4dfe9b8ed3fd2e2 height=662702 version=0x3fffe000 log2_work=92.537363 tx=599079525 date='2020-12-23T22:57:43Z' progress=0.883804 cache=19.9MiB(148732txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:25Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000c65ef4eaff05ee222feafa6d02bedd84d6a888683f08f height=662703 version=0x37ffe000 log2_work=92.537379 tx=599082148 date='2020-12-23T23:01:17Z' progress=0.883805 cache=21.1MiB(159087txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:25Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=6 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:25Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=699792, peer=8 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:26Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000059a642252fb80aaf53799dad22ed374fd12de2559611b height=662704 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=92.537395 tx=599084805 date='2020-12-23T23:11:54Z' progress=0.883808 cache=22.1MiB(167314txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:27Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x1000000 in rev02374.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:27Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000005dfca7d802d17937a3d51c4382048c5fe8161bc40f972 height=662705 version=0x20800000 log2_work=92.537411 tx=599087464 date='2020-12-23T23:13:44Z' progress=0.883809 cache=23.3MiB(177008txo)
2021-09-09T17:59:27Z socket send error An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  (10054)
2021-09-09T17:59:27Z Leaving block file 2374: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=105, size=134176805, heights=662605...662720, time=2020-12-23...2020-12-24)
2021-09-09T17:59:27Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x1000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:28Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=9 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:28Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x2000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:29Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x3000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:31Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x4000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:32Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x5000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:33Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x6000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:34Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=10 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:35Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x7000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:35Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=11 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:35Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=12 (full-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:36Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x8000000 in blk02375.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:36Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=699792, peer=13 (block-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:36Z Leaving block file 2375: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=105, size=133974329, heights=662721...662899, time=2020-12-24...2020-12-25)
2021-09-09T17:59:36Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x1000000 in blk02376.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:37Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=699792, peer=14 (block-relay)
2021-09-09T17:59:37Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x2000000 in blk02376.dat
2021-09-09T17:59:37Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x3000000 in blk02376.dat
```

Then everything in the debug file looked normal for a while, no additional errors, and similar to the first two examples, the file just ends abruptly.

```
2021-09-09T18:05:53Z Pre-allocating up to position 0x1000000 in rev02383.dat
2021-09-09T18:05:53Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000008fb78a774809bdae71c742f511884a2341ad660c99b5d height=663624 version=0x3fff0000 log2_work=92.552107 tx=600974687 date='2020-12-30T06:21:43Z' progress=0.886620 cache=578.2MiB(4252360txo)
2021-09-09T18:05:54Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000cf50f299fed02a5a825cc1688df823f9370715ee9d5e1 height=663625 version=0x20400000 log2_work=92.552123 tx=600975347 date='2020-12-30T06:24:28Z' progress=0.886621 cache=578.8MiB(4257291txo)
2021-09-09T18:05:54Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000036e746b5a99a681fe274e7a168c48438b82ae81a9d95b height=663626 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=92.552139 tx=600975580 date='2020-12-30T06:25:20Z' progress=0.886622 cache=579.5MiB(4262818txo)
2021-09-09T18:05:54Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000505744c84c5efa0d66c726eae8f711b3e1f0f20573c96 height=663627 version=0x2000e000 log2_work=92.552155 tx=600977293 date='2020-12-30T06:33:33Z' progress=0.886624 cache=579.7MiB(4264897txo)
```

Comment: It is far better to cut and paste logfile records than to post an image. We can't use text search etc in images.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Certainly appreciate the feedback as I'm new to this. Would the best practice be to just truly paste all the text in the post, or should the text be input in a specific way? I'm unfortunately away from the PC where I'm trying to install the node until Monday/Tuesday so depending on best practice maybe I should delete this and try reposting in a few days. Thanks again!

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Windows Update restarted the machine.

Comment: @HannahVernon - Is there any reason why this would've prevent me from fully downloading all the blocks? I would think if that's what happened I should've been able to just re-run it successfully when I next turned on the computer, but I seem to keep running into recurring issues where it never finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obvious in the log but there's a few items of interest

At 17:57:59 it says `Config file: D:\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf (not found, skipping)` which suggests you have specified a non-standard data directory, perhaps by a command-line option? The apparent absence of bitcoin.conf may be unusual - my installation has an empty file with that name.

Command line options when running Bitcoin-qt:

> -conf=
> Specify path to read-only configuration file. Relative paths will be prefixed by datadir location. (default: bitcoin.conf)
>
> -datadir=
> Specify data directory

Then at 17:58:27 there is `Failed to open mempool file from disk. Continuing anyway.` I've no idea if this is significant. It suggests an abnormal shutdown if you didn't previously set the option to not persist the mempool.

At 17:58:27 there is `Failed to open file D:\Bitcoin\anchors.dat` which confirms that bitcoin-qt didn't exit normally previously. It creates this file when it exits.

This doesn't give much direction for tracking down the problem.

You could create an empty `bitcoin.conf` and verify that the warning about that file goes away. You could perform a memory test to ensure that bitcoin-qt isn't using a lot of memory and therefore being affected by some problem not evident in less demanding applications - but this seems like a long shot. You could invoke bitcoin-qt.exe from a .bat file and put `echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%` after the invocation. Give that you had a pop-up error dialog stating`"couldn't access block #### data"` - you might have corrupt blockchain data files. There are open-source parsers that can read these blockchain files and that might help verify that one has a problem. You might need to uninstall, clean up, reinstall and restart.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I imagine the the improper shutdown was the computer resetting at some point. The path is not standard as I have the blockchain loaded on a external Samsung SSD so it's not on the bootdrive (this shouldn't cause issues normally should it?). I'm still not totally sure what went wrong previously, but I ran the reindex feature and came back this morning with the client totally synced and finished, so that seemed to fix it somehow.

Comment: So a few times now I've come back to this computer after leaving it alone for a few days and I come back to "error reading from database, shutting down". This has happened twice now in the last couple days and then I just re-run bitcoin-qt and it typically resyncs the missing blocks in just a few minutes and gets back up-to-date. Any idea what would be driving this? The computer is brand new.